# Apache Camel 3.17 Adoptium JDK 17 Error IllegalAccessError: failed to access class registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling, java-17, javax.activation, mimemultipart

`I have migrated Camel 3.20 to JDK 17 Adoptium.

When calling ".unmarshal().mimeMultipart()" at the beginning of the route, the following error occurs. I am slowly running out of ideas.

Stacktrace:

2023-03-21 10:18:24,915 [http-nio-8080-exec-303] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: 946A7B8039EA3B9-00000000000000D0 on ExchangeId: 946A7B8039EA3B9-00000000000000D0). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[946A7B8039EA3B9-00000000000000D0]. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[null]

### Message History (source location and message history is disabled)

Source                                   ID                             Processor                                          Elapsed (ms)
route100/route100              from[servlet:/blobstore/upload?httpMethodRestrict=    424647475

### Stacktrace

org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange:

```
`Exchange[946A7B8039EA3B9-00000000000000D0]
    at org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AbstractExchange.setException(AbstractExchange.java:597)
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:27)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:818)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:726)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doExecute(CamelServlet.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:214)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at de.ongeo.camel.filter.VersionInfoFilter.doFilter(VersionInfoFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:881)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap (com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport and javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @69abfa3c)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.<init>(MailcapCommandMap.java:149)
    at javax.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:55)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:137)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:596)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:524)
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.mime.multipart.MimeMultipartDataFormat.unmarshal(MimeMultipartDataFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:76)
    ... 56 common frames omitted`
```

*Migrate to Camel 3.20.2
*Use latest JDK 17 from Adoptium
*experiment with the dependencies from
implementation group: 'com.sun.activation', name: 'jakarta.activation', version: '2.0.1'
implementation group: 'jakarta.activation', name: 'jakarta.activation-api', version: '2.1.1'`

Comment: Excluding this Dependencies in Gradle solved my problem with Camel 3.17 and Adoptium 17: 
`configurations.all {       
exclude group: 'com.sun.activation', module: 'jakarta.activation'       exclude group: 'jakarta.activation'           
exclude group: 'org.eclipse.angus', module: 'angus-activation'  
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need Camel 4 for Java 17 and Jakarta EE support.

Camel 3.x is Java 11 and is NOT Jakarta EE compatible (its only javax)